# MySql Toad if now rows return value

Tags: mysql, toad, coalesce, ifnull

I am using **mysql toad**, i have a table which is empty and i am trying to return a string value if no records are found i have tried the under mention queries however none works, only an empty row is returned.

**Query**

```
select coalesce(stDate,'0')as StDate from tblStudents where studentNumber = 12213123;

select IFNULL(stDate,'0')as StDate from tblStudents where studentNumber = 12213123;
```

The results are only empty strings the column stDate is of type varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 select Cast(count(*) as char(10)) as StDate
 from tblStudents where studentNumber = 12213123;
```

You can also use the CASE statement, and if the Student Number is unique, the max() or min() functions to get the stDate from the table.

```
 select Cast(count(*) as char(10)) as NumRows,max(stDate) as stDate
 from tblStudents where studentNumber = 12213123;
```

If you only want a single field, try something like this

```
select 
CASE count(*)
    WHEN 0 THEN ''
    ELSE CAST(max(stDate) as char(12))
END CASE as StartDate
     from tblStudents where studentNumber = 12213123;
```

Comment: what if there are records and i want to return the stDate

Comment: i just want a select that returns one value not two your select has a count and a date if there is no date i will get a count of zero and if there is data i will get a count of 1 and a date not what i am looking for

Comment: think i will try the case statement if the count is > 0 then select a date